# C++ Can't reference key of the map

Tags: c++, stdmap

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int steps;
    map<string, string> countries;
    cin >> steps;
    for (int i = 0; i < steps; ++i) {
        string command;
        cin >> command;
        if(command == "CHANGE_CAPITAL") {
            for(auto& s : countries) {
                string& old_country = s.first;
                string& old_capital = s.second;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Hello! When I try to compile this code it gives me error:

> binding value of type 'basic_string<...>' to reference to type
>   'basic_string<...>' drops 'const' qualifier

for the string

```
string& old_country = s.first;
```

Why does this happen? (it doesn't give this error for the next string - where I assing "s.second" by reference).

Compiler is ISO C++ 1y (-std=c++1y).

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
const string& old_country = s.first;
```

Or even better:

```
const auto& old_country = s.first;
```

Side note: for readability, add the `const` even for auto.

The pair for your map is:

```
std::pair<const std::string, string>
```

because the key cannot be modified due to the tree constraint.

Comment: i'd say that `const auto& old_country = s.first;` is better. It will prevent the next person looking at OPs code having the same confusion as OP is having now.

Comment: Yes, you can indeed always put the `const` in and would help readability indeed.

Comment: I mean there is no genericity in that `const`, the key type may change, but it will always be `const`, so why not be explicit about it